# Changing Route Config impact on ajax url and embedding controller name in request (Mulitple Time)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My all ajax calls unexpectedly appending controller name **twice** in ajax calls by changing following line

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

to

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I changed this line because i found a extra redirect, that first user will go to home and then from there he will be redirected to login page due to authorization failure. have a look at following console error

> http://localhost:51381/Document/Document/GetCategoriesByDocumentType?categoryDocumentType=1&_=1480570187959
>   404 (Not Found)

as you can see that two controller name was appended.

> /Document/Document/

My ajax call in separate Js file.

> var url = 'Document/GetDocumentGrid?CategoryDocumentType=' +
>   CategoryDocumentType + '&categoryId=' + CategoryList + '&keywords=' +
>   search + '&isArchived=' + isArchived;

and when i revert route config , all ajax call works as expected.

what if i wanted my user to go on login page directly, instead of home? or i have to change all my ajax URL's ? And what is the reason of this behavior?

Note: i cannot use any Razor syntax as i have separate js files and i dont want to change every Js file, as my project goes almost 90 pages :(

Comment: You missing the leading `/` - `var url = '/Document/....` But you should always use `@Url.Action(...)` to generate the correct url (and then pass it to the external file)

Comment: if leading / is the issue then why it is working when routes are to go at home page ?? i mention that problem occurs after i changed the routes.